# Background service only activating when Application is closed

Tags: android-studio

Strangely, my service does run in the background, however it only creates the alarm when the application is closed, and not when it is running. Can anyone provide some insight as to why this may be happening. My service class below.

```
public class TimeDifferenceService extends Service {
DatabaseHelper myDbs;


public boolean notificationCheck;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



    myDbs = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeChecker,100);
   return START_STICKY;
}
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable mUpdateTimeChecker = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do whatever you want to change here, like:


        Cursor res = myDbs.GetFirstTime();
        if (res.getCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            String booleancheck =res.getString(5);
            notificationCheck = Boolean.parseBoolean(booleancheck);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();

            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
            Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));



            try {
                c1.setTime(sdf.parse(res.getString(1)));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            c2.getTime();
            long timeDiff = ((c1.getTimeInMillis()-c2.getTimeInMillis())/(1000*60));

            if (timeDiff <= 60 && timeDiff >=0 && !notificationCheck){
                setAlarm();
                String notifDisplay = "true";
                update(res.getInt(0),notifDisplay);
            }else {

            }

            res.close();
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);
    }

};
public void setAlarm(){
    long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+1*1000;
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this,AlertReciever.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alertTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

}
```

}